# Displaying profile in view confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So I am working on a personal project to learn about rails nesting and I decided to use Devise. I created a profile model and controller to handle displaying other information the user will input at a later time. And utilized `after_create :create_profile` to handle the heavy lifting. I finally have everything setup in the model and controllers so that information is passed correctly, but when it comes to actually displaying the user's profile is where my confusion arises.

This is my profile controller

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_profile
  before_action :find_user
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = current_user.create_profile(profile_params)
  end

  def show
    @profile = @user.profile
  end

  def update
    @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
    end
  end

  private

    def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def find_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:tagline, :age, :website)
    end
end
```

In rails console, I can manipulate the data quite easily, but in practical use (the view) I find it to be not the case.

Example being if I want to display the second user's profile, in rails console, I can simple do this.

`@u = User.find(params[:id])` to find the user, then I can do `@u.profile` to grab his associated profile.

Since I am going to be looking for users quite a bit, it made sense to me to create a method and use a `before_action`. So I thought I would be able to do the following in view `<%= @user.profile.tagline %> to grab the user's tagline from their tagline. But that's not working out too well. I also tried`@profile.user.tagline`, which displays nothing (no error is thrown because I added`attr_accessor` for tagline on the user model).

Anyone have any suggestions? A hint as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: care to post your logs? What does not working out too well mean?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant it doesn't display at all. I'm relatively new to rails so what logs would I grab in particular? The information that's displayed after start a rails server?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I can see is, you are using `params[:id]` to find both `User` and `Profile`. I assume only one should be correct.

So first try to find out when id you are passing (this can be figured from the link you call the profile page)

Then try to print both @user and @profile variables in your page. you can do it by (in your view Ex)

```
#show.html.erb
<%= @user.inspect %>
<%= @profile.inspect %>
```

and if you are comfortable with dig in it to more details, you can use a debugger gem like [pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails)

Comment: I figured it out, well not really. I restarted my rails server and it worked.
As for the `params[:id]` for both fields, I honestly thought my profile param should have been `params[:profile_id]` but it throws an error saying such can't be found, but when I use `params[:id]` it works as expected!

Comment: @BronzeTax, glad you got it working. as a convention rails uses params[:id] and refer to the id of the object that controller belongs to. (in your case profile), however this can be changed easily

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, well not really figured it out. It just started working when I restarted my rails server.

Let this be a lesson kids, sometimes instead of ripping everything apart and putting it back together...just try restarting your rails server ha!